# Plot Mandelbrot with matplotlib / pyplot / numpy / python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scientific-computing

I am new to python and learning by following Python "Scientific lecture notes Release 2013.1" tutorial. Please help me solve this Mandelbrot problem in the srcreenshot below (Pg 71). Please provide step-wise commands with explanation if possible because programming concepts are new to me.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50511173/mandelbrot.png

I tried to solve this as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y=np.ogrid[-2:1:10j,-1.5:1.5:10j]
c=x + 1j*y
z=0
for g in range(50):
  z=z**2 + c

plt.imshow(z.T, extent=[-2,1,-1.5,1.5])
```

I encountered the following error "TypeError: Image data can not convert to float"

What does this error exactly mean and how to correct it? I am finding it difficult to understand the imshow() function. What do the individual terms inside imshow() mean?

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mandelbrot set is not the values of `z` you are trying to plot, which are giving you problems because they are complex numbers.  The Mandelbrot set is made up of the points `p` of the complex plane for which the recurrence relation `z_n = z_n-1**2 + p` remains bounded. This is checked in a practical way by comparing the result after a few iterations to some threshold. In your case, if you add the following lines after your `for` loop:

```
threshold = 2
mask = np.abs(z) < threshold
```

and then plot `mask` you should see the set plot on screen.

To understand the general workings of `imshow`'s arguments, you will be better off reading the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) than asking here.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @Jan and @Jaime. I got it working as follows, takes too much time to calculate though:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x,y=np.ogrid[-2:1:5000j,-1.5:1.5:5000j]

print('')
print('Grid set')
print('')

c=x + 1j*y
z=0

for g in range(500):
        print('Iteration number: ',g)
        z=z**2 + c

threshold = 2
mask=np.abs(z) < threshold

print('')
print('Plotting using imshow()')
plt.imshow(mask.T,extent=[-2,1,-1.5,1.5])

print('')
print('plotting done')
print('')

plt.gray()

print('')
print('Preparing to render')
print('')

plt.show()
```

[image: Image Result]

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because `plt.imshow` does not accept arrays of complex numbers. You can address the real or imaginary part of an array `Z` as `Z.real` or `Z.imag`. Thus if you want to plot the real part

```
plt.imshow(z.real.T, extent=[-2,1,-1.5,1.5])
```

would do the job.

The arguments in 'imshow' define the following things.

If `z` is a N-by-M matrix, it is interpreted as point values on a regular grid. By `extent` you specify how this grid extends in space...

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to plot a complex value with imshow which is why you're getting that error, can use a threshold as others have suggested, but you might want to consider using `np.angle` or `np.abs` as well. You can also simplify your calculation of z using Python's built-in `reduce` method.

Had some fun with this one, but this shows the general idea:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

x, y = np.ogrid[-2:1:500j, -1.5:1.5:500j]

# Increase this to improve the shape of the fractal
iterations = 9

c = x + 1j*y

z = reduce(lambda x, y: x**2 + c, [1] * iterations, c)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(np.angle(z));

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(np.log(np.abs(z)));
```